# WinForm ComboBox add text "Select" after data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, .net-4.0, combobox

At my form, I have one control ComboBox. I want after databinding add text "Select". I try this

```
cbOperatorList.DataSource = operatorService.GetOperatorList();
cbOperatorList.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

But when I do this. I get exception what

> Changing the collection of items is impossible if you set the property
>   DataSource.

**UPDATE**

```
public BindingList<Operator> GetOperatorList(string filter = "")
{
            return
                new BindingList<Operator>(
                    this.operatorRepository.All.Where(
                        item => item.FirtsName.Contains(filter) || item.LastName.Contains(filter) || item.MiddleName.Contains(filter)).
                        ToList());
}
```

**UPDATE**

I fixed the problem, using this code

```
cbOperatorList.DataSource =
                this.operatorService.GetOperatorList().Concat(new[] { new Operator { LastName = "Select", Id = 0 } }).OrderBy(
                    item => item.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `GetOperatorList()` returns an immutable `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use linq to concatenate that with `new object[] { "Select" }`.  Assuming that `T` is not `object`, you would have to cast:

```
cbOperatorList.DataSource = operatorService
    .GetOperatorList()
    .Cast<object>()
    .Concat(new object[] { "Select" });
```

**EDIT**

If you want the word "Select" to appear at the beginning, reverse the concatenation:

```
cbOperatorList.DataSource = (new object[] { "Select" })
    .Concat(
        operatorService.GetOperatorList().Cast<object>()
     );
```

Comment: @Greg see edited post if you want "Select" at the beginning.  If you want it somewhere in the middle, it gets more complicated.

Comment: Your code work is wrong. Because the data displayed is wrong. I see only "Select" text, and then objects

Answer (score 1):

You don't describe what `GetOperatorList()` returns, but you could first set a variable to get that list and insert your item in the list *before* setting the DataSource to that variable.

You would have to refactor your code to handle this "Select" item to not get confused with your operator objects.