# insert item in combobox after binding it from a Dataset in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have to insert "Select" at top after combobox is bound from dataset.i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751701/winform-combobox-add-text-select-after-data-binding) but it isn't working.Throws error "dataset doesn't have any definition for cast".I think i am not using it properly.Commented code is the part i tried but not working.

```
cmbCategory.DataSource = dsCat.Tables[0];
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
// cmbCategory.Items.Add("Select");
// cmbCategory.SelectedText = "Select";
// cmbCategory.DataSource =(new object[] { "Select" }).Concat(this.liveReportingDalc.GetCategoriesByType(CategoryType.RegistrationType).Cast<object>());
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to Insert to the object you are databinding to rather than to the combobox. You can't insert directly into the combobox.

You can use this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName");

DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["CategoryName"] = "Select";
dr["ID"] = 0;

dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);

cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
cmbCategory.DataSource = dt;
cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

This is very straight forward example.

Comment: I tried your suggested way but I am getting error that says `A column named 'CODE' already belongs to this DataTable.`

Answer (score 8):

You cannot add items to a `ComboBox` after binding it to a data source. To add or remove items from a `ComboBox` with a bound data source, you have to do it through data source itself.

You can insert a `DataRow` into your table and it will be automatically added to your `ComboBox`. Try the following:

```
 DataRow dr = dsCat.Tables[0].NewRow();
 dr["CategoryName"] = "Select";
 dr["ID"] = 123;// Some ID
 dsCat.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
```

Comment: @abramlimpin You have to call Add on the Rows-property of the Table. I've edited the code with that update

Answer (score 0):

```
// cmbCategory.DataSource =(new object[] { "Select" }).Concat(this.liveReportingDalc.GetCategoriesByType(CategoryType.RegistrationType).Cast<object>());
```

You might be able to do this, but your syntax is wrong somehow.

Maybe you can split it up until you figure it out and then compress it back into in-line functions.

```
List <object> catData = new List <object> { "Select" };

DataSet catByType = this.liveReportingDalc.GetCategoriesByType(CategoryType.RegistrationType);

foreach(DataRow oRow in catByType.Tables[0].Rows)
{ catData.Add(oRow.ItemArray[0]); }
```

But for this to work you need to consolidate your understanding of the data coming back from the `GetCategoriesByType` function.  Will the objects be text like "Select"?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *dsCat.Rows.Add* method.

```
dsCat.Rows.Add(0, "Other"); // this will add row
cmbCategory.DataSource = dsCat.Tables[0];
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "ID";
```