# Using Lists From DataSource but including a Not Selected Item

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an UI both web and winds which has a dropdown control that is used to populate a field on an the object.

It is not required to be set.   I'm thinking that having an additional item "" in the dropdown would be a good way and then detecting this when saving and setting its value to null.

However as the datasource is a IList coming from LINQ query of an EF/SQL database I really don't want to create additional records in the database but want to add these purely for UI controls.

Is this a good strategy ?

Comment: you can't add directly to dropdown, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374880/insert-item-in-combobox-after-binding-it-from-a-dataset-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

When I was managing a "Default" value I would set it either in the JavaScript (the front end data binding library we used had a way to set a null initially selected value with display text, we used `--- Select ---` but it was customizable per control) or on the server inserting it as the first item in the list after building from my data store.

Both are a valid option of handling a null, however I found the front end library easier since it would just pass a null for the value and I didn't have to transform a blank / default into a null server side to store.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension method to add a null value on your `IList`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T first) {
    yield return first;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FollowedBy<T>(this T first, IEnumerable<T> rest) => first.AsSingleton().Concat(rest);
```

Then set the datasource as

```
ddlPick.DataSource = "".FollowedBy(query);
```

Comment: The list is of Type Component which has a serial number and  a product property which has a manufacturer. property.    

The list I'm displaying generates a description based upon the product and manufacturer names and hence it is not a simple property on a single entity.   So creating first entity ends up being more complicated.

I was thinking about having a button next to the list which simply sets the value to null.   It is simple and works but I think it is cludgy.